# ejabberd Cluster Not Working

Tags: cluster-computing, ejabberd

I've set up a ejabberd (v 15.04) cluster on AWS using 2 Ubuntu images. Whilst I am able to successfully cluster the two (using the command join_cluster from the 2nd node to the 1st node), I am not sure if the behavior is as expected... any thoughts would be much appreciated...

To detail the above, 2 different clients connected to the 2 nodes separately can communicate with each other. However, when I stop the server on the secondary node, I would still expect the two clients to be able to talk to each other. But instead, this 2nd client simply gets disconnected as the server is not running.

Is there something possibly that am overlooking here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

join two node with join_as_master() method.
cluster code is available on github site.
for doing the Ejabberd Clustering I followed the steps from the link below :
Link : http://chadillac.tumblr.com/post/35967173942/easy-ejabberd-clustering-guide-mnesia-mysql

I hav done the Clustering with no mysql tables only mnesia database

Imp Note :
1) The ejabberd.yml file should be same as in the master host.

2) Copy the .erlang.cookies file frm the master to the slaves

3) The slave host name will be mentioned in the ejabberdctl.cfg which will different from that mentioned in yml file of the slave.

4) For my sql, as in we are creating a totally different machine ..no need to add into the cluster.

Comment: @Mickaël Rémond, the tumblr link can't be found.